# How to use Defer in canjs

Tags: jquery, promise, canjs, canjs-model

```
Featoff = can.Model.extend("featoff",{
        findAll: {
        url: '/api.php/specialoffers?',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { max : 10 , pid : 977 , sid : 5934 }
        }
      }, {});

Feat = can.Control({ init: function()
 { var that = this; can.view('images/js/mn/temps/featured.ejs', featoff.findAll({}).then(function(d) 
{ return { offerdata : d, secTitle : that.element.data('title') }; })).done(function(frag) 
{ that.element.html(frag); }) }});
```

I am calling this using new Feat();

this is working now. 
So now I wanna reuse the same Feat control with different set of parameters in the findAll, How can i do so? What method to use and how to use?? also can I also defer or override the can.view for the same ??

Can I also have a single Base controller and just keep overriding the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

To override the view you can extend your Feat object `FeatExtended = Feat.extend{` and use a different view in the init method.

You can also give parameters when calling `new Feat({view : MY_VIEW})`. An options object is passed to init() as describe [here](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.html#sig_newcan_Model__options__).

For you findAll question, you should define findAll as a method as describe in the [documentation](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.findAll.html#section_ImplementwithaFunction)

Hope that helps !

EDIT :

For example : you can pass a params object defining an option to be added in URL and the method of the HTTP call

```
Featoff = can.Model.extend({
  findAll : function(params){
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/api.php/specialoffers?' + params.myoption,
      type: params.method,
      dataType: 'json'})
  }
},{})
```

Comment: well I got a brief idea but can i get an example ??

Comment: So can I have a basemodel say

BaseModel = can.Model.extend({
  findAll : function(params){
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/api.php/specialoffers?' + params.myoption,
      type: params.method,
      dataType: 'json'})
  }
},{})

And use findAll in the control and override the data.

So I will call the next A = can.control.extend({
Basemodel.findAll({url, type})});